# Why do major software companies hesitate about 64-bit applications?

Tags: architecture, 64-bit

I believe the most CPUs out there support x64 natively nowaday. I thought 64-bit applications are faster and more reliable than 32-bit ones. Why don't software companies just release 64-bit applications?

For example, Google Chrome is 32-bit. Microsoft Office, Visual Studio, and Adobe Photoshop is 32-bit. The default download option for CPython is 32-bit. And many other major applications...

Is there something more than I thought?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason may be that there are still a lot of 32-bit computers out there still (XP was just EOL and a lot of XP machines were just 32-bit).

Another reason may be that a 64-bit program will generally require more RAM than a 32-bit program.  (Although more and more computers are getting 4gb+ these days).

In terms of MS Office and VStudio I know Microsoft Cares about backwards compatibility a lot. They probably wanted most of these programs to be able to be ran on older Machines.